# Authentication with Firebase Auth UI doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am following the instructions in [Firebase in a weekend](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352/)

When I start the app, I am asked to choose an account. But when I choose the account, the same layer is showing up again and again. Happens on emulator and real device.

[image]

In the course it looks like this:

[image]

Do you have any tips?

EDIT:
MainActivity.java:
    package de.marcofriedmann.testlabor:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

// Choose an arbitrary request code value
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // initialize Firebase
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is logged in
                String username = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                TextView welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcomeText.setText(username);
            } else {
                // User is logged out
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code from the Activity? First of all, onActivityResult() and how do you initialize googleApiClient.

Comment: I added the code in the question. I forgot to enter the sha1 debug certificate in firebase console. Now that I did it, I am able to login. But my screenshot still looks the same and not like in the course